# Как вывести данные массива в случайном порядке?

Tags: javascript, html

```
var points = ['http://p5f6e.com/click/1',
  'http://p5f6e.com/click/2',
  'http://p5f6e.com/click/3',
  'http://p5f6e.com/click/4',
  'http://p5f6e.com/click/5'];

<a href='#'>now</a>
```

Чтобы при каждой загрузке сайта загружалась новая ссылка.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) вполне справится.

```js
var points = ['http://p5f6e.com/click/1',
  'http://p5f6e.com/click/2',
  'http://p5f6e.com/click/3',
  'http://p5f6e.com/click/4',
  'http://p5f6e.com/click/5'];
  
  console.log(points[Math.floor(Math.random()*points.length)]);
```

Подставить в `href` полученную ссылку можно таким образом:

```
var link = document.getElementById("link");
link.href = points[Math.floor(Math.random()*points.length)];
```

в документе соответственно должна быть ссылка с *id="link"*

Весь код в работе:

```js
var points = ['http://p5f6e.com/click/1',
  'http://p5f6e.com/click/2',
  'http://p5f6e.com/click/3',
  'http://p5f6e.com/click/4',
  'http://p5f6e.com/click/5'
];

var link = document.getElementById("link");
link.href = points[Math.floor(Math.random() * points.length)];
```

```html
<a href="" id="link">now</a>
```

**Обновлено**
Судя по комментариям у Вас `js` срабатывает до того, как построился DOM.
Можно либо добавить `.js` в конец (перед `</body>`). Либо можно повесить обработчик на загрузку DOM:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var points = ['http://p5f6e.com/click/1',
        'http://p5f6e.com/click/2', 'http://p5f6e.com/click/3',
        'http://p5f6e.com/click/4', 'http://p5f6e.com/click/5'
    ];
    var link = document.getElementById("link");
    link.href = points[Math.floor(Math.random() * points.length)];
});
```

Comment: Спасибо. А как этот скрипт вывести в <a>NOW</a>

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: @user218215 В скрытом примере ("Показать код") всё работает, как Вам требуется? Какие ошибки в консоли и куда "вставляете код"?

Comment: подставил в код не работает((

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'href' of null Вот что пишет в консоли

Comment: Ссылка (`<a href="" id="link">now</a>`) Должна находиться в разметке страницы (никак не .js файле и не в `<script></script>`). Грубо говоря, в `.html` файле. А всё, что выше ссылки (из примера выше), как раз таки должно находиться либо в `.js` файле, либо в `<script></script>` Более (на основании входных данных) ничего предположить не могу.

Comment: Это значит, что не удалось найти элемент с таким `id`. js скорей всего у Вас отрабатывает раньше чем построился DOM. Сейчас обновлю ответ.

Comment: переместил код в конец страницы. Вроде заработал) Спасибо

Comment: а если через class. var link = document.getElementsByClassName('link');  Так будет выглядеть?

Comment: ссылка просто не одна их 3

Comment: Почти, только следует добавить индекс: `var link = document.getElementsByClassName('link')[0];`. Это конструкция вернёт первую найденную ссылку в документе с классом `link`. Если же их несколько, и ко всем надо присвоить `href`, то надо перебирать в цикле все ссылки которые получили. Примерно так: [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/kixkix/5511ygrf/)

Comment: спасибо огромное, очень выручил)))