# Отображение нижней части блока с overflow-y: auto;

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть чат, в котором выводятся все сообщение в блоке у которого фиксированная высота и overflow-y: auto;
Нужно, чтобы при открытии страницы, в данном чате показывались последние сообщения , которые находятся внизу блока. А сейчас, чтобы их просмотреть, нужно скроллить ручками. 
Как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Можно например использовать [scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop), который установит количество пикселей, которые требуется отступить сверху. Нужное количество `px` же можно узнать используя [scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight)

Итого:

```js
var chat = document.getElementById('chat');
chat.scrollTop = chat.scrollHeight;
```

```css
.chat {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red
}
.chat p {
  height: 2px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat" id="chat">
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
var chat = document.getElementsByClassName('chat_bottom');
chat.scrollTop = chat.scrollHeight;
</script>                                                                                                        <div class="content chat_bottom"  id="content">сюда js подтягивает контент</div> но что-то не срабатывает. Делаю через class

Comment: [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) возвращает коллекцию. Если уж используете его, то делайте так: `var chat = document.getElementsByClassName('chat_bottom')[0];` (с указанием индекса `[0]` - первый элемент с классом `chat_bottom` на странице). И не `.chat_bottom`, а `chat_bottom` (без точки).

Comment: уже и так и так пробовал( попробовал ваш код просто в html, не в сайт встроить, но увы, скролл все равно вверху <script type="text/javascript">
 var chat = document.getElementById('chat');
 chat.scrollTop = chat.scrollHeight;
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.chat {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red
}
.chat p {
  height: 2px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
</style>

<div class="chat" id="chat">
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
</div>

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript"> ... </script>` разместите после `html-разметки`. (перед `</body>`), _зы. Забавно, второй день подряд мне попались вопросы с одной проблемой_  [вопрос вчера](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/558777/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B5/558782#558782) почитайте в комментариях, проблема судя по всему такая же.

Comment: забавно, получилось) но вот на сайте увы, может это связано с тем, что контент в родительский блок, у которого overflow-y: auto; приходит через JS?

Comment: Вполне вероятно. Тогда `chat.scrollTop = chat.scrollHeight;` надо рассчитывать в том месте кода, где происходит "подтягивание контента". Лучше в вопросе указывать минимальный фрагмент кода, для воспроизведения проблемы. (В любой момент можно отредактировать и дополнить вопрос)

Comment: да проблема в том, что чужой код( и тут пока разберешься, с ума сойдешь((